# Diagonalise matrix iff eigenvectors independent (True/False)

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that
we can
**diagonalise a matrix** iff **eigenvectors are independent**? I think so, but I'm not sure.

---

Clarification: lets say I, for some matrix **A**, find eigenvalues a, b, and c. The eigenvectors *associated with those eigenvalues* I will call **a**, **b**, **c**. We know that a ≠ b ≠ c <=> **a**, **b**, **c** are independent.

Now, my question is if this statement is true

> **a**, **b**, **c** are independent <=> we can diagonalise a matrix **A**.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "eigenvectors are independent"? There are often infinitely many eigenvectors!

Comment: I agree with Thomas: the question should be clarified. Having said that, keep in mind that if $u_1,\dots ,u_N$ are eigenvectors associated with distinct eigenvalues, then they are independent; but not all matrices can be diagonalized.

Comment: @ThomasBelulovich: Why only "often"? Do you have finite fields in mind?

Comment: @Roland Yes :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of sami is notable. The main point is the number of such independent eigenvectors, so i think the best is to say

> **The matrix $A$ ($n×n$) is diagonalizable if and only if there exist $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.**

The result in this form is true

Answer (score 4):

No, **this is not true**: for example the matrix
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$
has only one eigenvalue $1$ and the eigenspace is $\operatorname{span}\left\{e_1=(1,0)^T\right\}$ hence $(e_1)$ is linearly independent but $A$ isn't diagonalizable.

However, if the eigenvectors form a **basis** of the linear space then the matrix is diagonalizable and the result is true.

Comment: It's all about that basis. I should have highlighted that too!

Answer (score 0):

It is true we can diagonalize a matrix IFF we have an eigenvector-basis of this matrix. Using a basis consisting of eigenvectors implies that the eigenvectors are independent Sidenote: Realize that 2 independent eigenvectors may not always have to come from distinct eigenvalues. Meaning it is possible that one eigenvalue can produce two independent eigenvectors. But disctinct eigenvalues do produce independent eigenvectors.